# hasClass condition not changing css in else Jquery

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I'm using a onepage scroll template and added my own navbar. On page scroll I need to animate the navbar. Once you scroll the body will change class from 
'fp-viewing-0' to 'fp-viewing-1-0' and so on. If from fp-viewing-0 go to fp-viewing-1-0 it will animate with no issue, but once I go back it won't animate anymore. This is my solution. Any suggestion how to fix this?

```
window.setInterval( function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-1-0')){
        $('.circle').animate({
            top:'30'
        });
        $('#menuBar').animate({
            backgroundColor: '#fff',

        }).css({
            borderBottom: '1px solid #f3f3f3'
        });
        $('#menuBarWrapper').css({
            boxShadow:' 0 0 10px #333'
        });
        console.log('white');
    }

        if($('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-0')){
        $('.circle').animate({
            top:'0'
        });
        $('#menuBar').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'none',

        }).css({
            borderBottom: 'none'
        });
        $('#menuBarWrapper').css({
            boxShadow:'none'
        });
        console.log('white');
    }



},10);
```

Comment: I know that this is not the anser, but if I were you, I would animate your element by CSS. Just check if body has a className and put your boxShadow, Top, backgroundColor and borderBottom properties to CSS.

Comment: use `$(window).scroll(function(){ ... });`

Comment: It will not work  @Tamil Selvan C

Comment: I think it has something to do with queing animations.

Comment: Try this one, I made it via CSS animations: https://jsfiddle.net/6jo3dvzg/3/

Comment: @exoslav thank you very much mate! it works like a charm, please make it as an answer it will be be very useful for other people. very grateful

Comment: @Sivvio can you mark my answer as a correct on please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit different code, where animations are made via CSS depending what class is currently active on body element. From my experince, I am trying to avoid jQuery animations, they are too slow compared to CSS animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/6jo3dvzg/3/

```
<div id="test">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div id="menuBar">menuBar</div>
  <div id="menuBarWrapper">menuBarWrapper</div>
  <div class="fp-viewing-0">fp-viewing-0</div>
  <div class="fp-viewing-1-0">fp-viewing-1-0</div>
</div>

handleScroll()
$(window).on('scroll', handleScroll)

function handleScroll() {
  var curr = $(window).scrollTop()

  if(curr >= $('#test .fp-viewing-0').offset().top) {
    $('body').removeClass().addClass('fp-viewing-0')
  }

  if(curr >= $('#test .fp-viewing-1-0').offset().top) {
    $('body').removeClass().addClass('fp-viewing-1-0')
  }

  console.log($('body').attr('class'))
}
```